# Is it possible to modify Chatter Email Notifications?

Tags: email, chatter, case, notification

We have now implemented Communities for most of our customers. Therefore we are using Chatter instead of Case Comments and are considering if / how we could customize the automatic Email Notification. We'd like to have the Case Number in the subject or at least in header or footer. Additional it would be great to modify the text body, e.g. Tag customers or add some Case informations.

Does anyone have experience with this or has already modified it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customise the emails directly. Yes you could implement your own email notifications via triggers but gets complicated. You would need to support feed, feedcomment and private message objects. Which would also need to support the different feed capabilities (poll, file, approval & link posts etc). What if the user switches on the standard chatter notifications? Ok now you have to surpress that config page in communities. Then build an inbound email class to handle replies. IMO not worth it.

Answer (score -1):

this is something that you can actually do pretty easily.  You can do it though a few different ways, so it depends what you are looking for.  If you want to send this not using an email alert, you can do it entirely in a Flow with a "Send Email" element and build out your own Template and query the Users that need to be notified.  Another option is to have all of your Chatter Feed Items, using Process Builder, update a field on the Case that tracks them.  From there, you can run a workflow on anytime that field 'ischanged' to figure out when you need to send a notification.  You can also pass in other values from the Feed Item (Feed Item = Chatter Post in API backend).  This means, you could only pass out public messages, find who posted the message and grab their profile or something to create more dynamic workflow off of that... really the sky is the limit.  With this solution you also get to bring in an email alert with Case Fields, since you would be firing the workflow from a Case field.

Comment: if we customize chatter email notification how can group members can reply? Do we lose the SF native reply functionality? I want my group members can respond to customized email the comment should add to record like the native functionality. Any ideas?